# Migrating vmdk to vhdx with 2 internal drives and unable to boot in Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, mount, hyper-v, vmware-workstation, vhdx

I'm migrating from VMWare Workstation to Hyper-V. I have a specific VM that it has a single VMDK file with 2 distinct drives inside it, and I've been unable to get it to boot. I converted the VMDK file to VHD using WinImage, and then I used Hyper-V to convert from VHD to VHDX. I can tell it worked because I can mount the VHDX file, and it will successfully mount 2 distinct drives in my Windows 10 Professional, and all the data is there. When I boot up the VM in Hyper-V, I'm getting the `Start PKE over IPv4` message.
[image: Start PKE over IPv4]
After, I get this screen
[image: Boot]
I checked in PowerShell, and the boot sequence is correct

```
$boot = Get-VMFirmware -VMName "TravelCash Delphi 7"
$boot.BootOrder
VMName              BootType Device
------              -------- ------
VM10 Drive          HardDiskDrive (Name = 'Hard Drive on SCSI controller number 0 at location 0', VMName = ... 
VM10 Network        VMNetworkAdapter (Name = 'Network Adapter', VMName = 'TravelCash Delphi 7') [VMId = 'de...
```

Below are the mounts that I get then I mount the VHDX file:
[image: Mounts]
As you can see, 2 drives are mounted into Windows 10 when I ask to mount a single VMDX file, and Hyper-V is probably getting lost, and it's not finding the right partition to boot. Is there any way around this? Splitting the VHDX file into 2, one for each drive? Or maybe converting the mounted file into separeate VHDX files? Or simply telling Hyper-V to boot correctly? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I added a SCSI DVD with a Windows 10 ISO, and it displayed the message that it was booting from the ISO, and then it failed as well

[image: Booting with DVD]

Comment: What happens if you set a Windows boot ISO as the CD/DVD?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Boot with a "freash" Windows ISO on the CDRom, and re-install the OS?

Comment: See if the boot starts at all from the ISO. If it does, try to do Startup Repair. What is the Windows version of the VM?

Comment: Windows 7. I'll try to boot it with a Windows 10 media.. that's the only one I have

Comment: You may use it as test to see if the VM boots at all. But for startup repair you need to download a Windows 7 ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7). Note: To address me, add `@harrymc` to the comment so I'll be notified of your comment.

Comment: @harrymc It won't even boot with an ISO. I edited my original post with the print. So weird.

Comment: Did you use maybe a 64-bit ISO on a 32-bit VM?

Comment: @harrymc I'll generate a 32-bit to make sure, and try to boot

Comment: @harrymc with the 32-bit, it didn't even display the Press any key to boot from CD or DVD.. .. message. It's definitely 64 bits

Comment: If you are getting the Press any key to boot from CD or DVD message, then the BIOS at least is functional. Try with a Windows 7 64-bit ISO. If this doesn't work, then your VM is bad.

Comment: @harrymc I will try. But I just create the VM from scratch, and imported the migrated disk, so I think it is strange to be a VM problem.

Comment: According to your post, the disk suffered a few transformations which might have changed some parameters.

Comment: @harrymc the disks, yes. They were migrated from VMWare Workstation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 is not supported in Generation 2 VMs.  Generation 2 VMs must also be 64bit.

Beyond that, realize, that you've changed the entire underlying hardware here,  converting the disk type doesn't make up for the massive virtual hardware change (motherboard, disk controllers, etc).  Also, its important to remove the VMware Tools before doing any conversion.
You will need to use a Generation 1 VM if you want to use Windows 7 with Hyper-V.

See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/should-i-create-a-generation-1-or-2-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v

Comment: I was using Generation 2 VM. That is certainly one of the main issues.

Comment: I recreated with a Generation 1 VM, and it booted correctly. I was able to uninstall VMWare Tools later without a problem